# How to copy specific number of <option> items from one <select> to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have three dropdown lists (selects) per row, containing number from 1 to 20. First select defines the number of items of the other two selects in the row. i.e. from number 1-20...if a user selects 4 in first select, the other two selects should only have 4 item. See attached screen.

Question:
What is the best way to achieve this...? And since this is going to be replicated in a lot of places with little variations so a generic solution is my final goal...where I would pass primary select id (using onchange attribute) and the rest of the siblings will get updated.

VanillaJS/jQuery...doesn't matter much.

Thanks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asadmalik/7aNRZ/721/

```js
function updateDependent(elem){
console.log("id: " +elem.id);
console.log("value: " +elem.value);

console.log('siblings length: ' + $(this).siblings.length);

var mySelect = $('#protect');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});

}
```

```html
<select id="clean" onchange="updateDependent(this)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>

</select>

<select id="protect">
</select>
<select id="deodorize">
</select>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what is myOptions? in your code

Comment: that's where I am trying to copy options from parent select.

Comment: @Berkay def. not! this empties the parent list! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may clone your options according to the selected value in the first select.

```js
$('#clean').on('change', function (e) {
    $('#protect').empty().append($(this).clone().find('option:lt(' + this.value + ')')).val('1');
    $('#deodorize').empty().append($('#protect').clone().find('option')).val('1');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="clean">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>

</select>

<select id="protect">
</select>
<select id="deodorize">
</select>
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you very much. :)